# perl array elements Subtraction

Tags: arrays, perl

i have a array like below

> array=(411625,411626,411629,411629,411630)

I want to get the delta  in an array of  adjacent elements and output like below

```
---------------------------------
   1     2      3      4       5
411625-411626-411629-411629-411630
      1      3      0      1
```

Comment: Your input and output is different?

Comment: thanks that you point it out , and i had fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my @array=(411625, 411626, 411629, 411629, 411630);

say join "\t", 1 .. @array;
say join '-', @array;
say join "\t", map $array[$_] - $array[$_ - 1], 1 .. $#array;
```